# PHP Laravel alternate push based on condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have fields in the table
**most_viewed** and
**top_rated**

```
    $most_viewed_posts = Blog::where('most_viewed', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    $top_rated_posts = Blog::where('top_rated', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    $featured_collection = collect();
    foreach ($most_viewed_posts as $most_viewed_post)
        $featured_collection->push($most_viewed_post);
    foreach ($top_rated_posts as $top_rated_post)
        $featured_collection->push($top_rated_post);
    $featured_posts = $featured_collection->sortBy('id', SORT_NUMERIC)->reverse()->chunk(2);
```

What i'm trying to accomplish here is im chunking the results into 2. Because Im displaying it like on the picture below. It's a carousel. The first result in a chunk should be most_viewed and the second is top_rated.

[image]

Now the issue is sometimes, most_viewed post is in Top Rated column. Is it possible that the items in the chunk is always most_view and top_rated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you accomplish it in so complicated way?
Why not simply:

```php
$most_viewed_post = Blog::where('most_viewed', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
$top_rated_post = Blog::where('top_rated', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
$featured_posts = collect([$most_viewed_post, $top_rated_post]);
```

**Upd.**

To get a collection of pairs Most Viewed + Top Rated you can use `zip()` method (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-zip):

```php
$most_viewed_posts = Blog::where('most_viewed', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
$top_rated_posts = Blog::where('top_rated', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

$featured_collection = $most_viewed_posts->zip($top_rated_posts);

//later you can iterate them this way:
foreach($featured_collection as [$most_viewed, $top_rated]) {
    //...output
}
```

Comment: Im not only displaying 1 most_viewed. Im displaying all most_viewed items and so with top_rated. Like I said it's carousel. Per each carousel, there should be 1 most view and 1 top rated

Comment: @RandyCorpuz check out my updated answer. This way you can make a collection of pairs `[[most viewed1, top rated1], [most viewed2, top rated2], ...]`. You just need to take care of cases when two collections have different count of posts.

Comment: perfect.. thanks. didnt know zip collection exists.